# I have to display text in the place of image if image is not present

Tags: asp.net

I have to display text in the place of image if image is not present.
I have done the following >which doesn't give me any out put

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="label" style="display:none" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ename") %>' AlternateText='<%#Eval("ename") %>' />
```

Comment: The AlternateText property you are using, should do the trick. Can you share the HTML sent by the server to browser: using view source of your website.

Comment: which part i have to show?

Comment: <img id="repeater1_ctl00_label" src="amith" alt="image not present" style="border-width:0px;display:none" />

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed your markup, you have set the `style="display:none"`. This making image or its Alternate text not appear in the DOM.

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="label" style="display:none" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ename") %>' AlternateText='<%#Eval("ename") %>' />
```

You should do it like this:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="label"  ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ename") %>' AlternateText='<%#Eval("ename") %>' />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you ishan. But i have solved it using following code:<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="label" style="display:none"  Width="100px" ImageUrl=""  CssClass="label" Text='<%#Eval("ename")  %>'>
 </asp:HyperLink>

Comment: and called them in code begind on itembound so that accordingly displayed.once again thank you very much

Comment: No Worries, you may try the above code as best practices. I am not sure what are you trying to do.